# How to use find all to display a whole array based on a criteria?

Tags: groovy

I am having trouble outputting a whole array in groovy based on a criteria. Virtually what I want to do below is that if forenames in the array = 'Peter', then output all of the information belonging to Peter. At the moment I can get it to display the only the relevant Pater's firstnames but how do I output the who array information?

Virtually at the moment it outputs: `[Peter,Peter,Peter]`

I want it to output: `[1,Peter,Smith],[2,Peter,Jonea],[4,Peter,Patel]`

Code below:

```
def array = [[number: 1, forename: "Peter" , surname: "Smith"],
            [number: 2, forename: "Peter" , surname: "Jones"],
            [number: 3, forename: "Tom" , surname: "White"],
            [number: 4, forename: "Peter" , surname: "Patel"],
            [number: 5, forename: "George" , surname: "Woodburn"]]


def arrayForenameFindAll = array.forename.findAll{it == "Peter"}
```

Comment: `array.findAll(it.forename == "Peter")`?

Comment: @JBNizet What you suggested there will return a `List`of `Map`, not a `List` of `List`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def array = [[number: 1, forename: "Peter" , surname: "Smith"],
        [number: 2, forename: "Peter" , surname: "Jones"],
        [number: 3, forename: "Tom" , surname: "White"],
        [number: 4, forename: "Peter" , surname: "Patel"],
        [number: 5, forename: "George" , surname: "Woodburn"]]


def arrayForenameFindAll = array.findAll { it.forename == 'Peter' }*.values()
```

That will evaluate to a `List` of `List` like you described in the question.